# R aggregate - naming the resulting columns

Tags: r, dplyr

This is some example code (lifted from a tutorial) for producing summary numbers for repeat observations in a dataframe. It all works; I can specify any function I want to apply to `mtcars$mpg`. However, I am really struggling with what to do with the resulting dataframe, particularly the column names.

```
myData <- aggregate(mtcars$mpg,
    by = list(cyl = mtcars$cyl, gears = mtcars$gear),
    FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x),
                        n = length(x)))
```

Here is the (truncated) output, as expected:

```
  cyl gears     x.mean       x.sd        x.n
1   4     3 21.5000000         NA  1.0000000
2   6     3 19.7500000  2.3334524  2.0000000
3   8     3 15.0500000  2.7743959 12.0000000
...
```

But if I try to rename the columns it fails:

```
>>> rename(myData, 'mean' = 'x.mean', 'std' = 'x.std', 'count' = 'x.n')
Error: Unknown columns `x.mean`, `x.std` and `x.n`
```

This is because the column names are "nested" (??) in a weird way:

```
>>> colnames(myData)
"cyl"   "gears" "x"
```

How can I "simplify" this data frame into something more workable? I'm very confused as to why this seemingly convoluted mess of nested column names is default behavior...

Is there a more friendly `tidyverse` aggregate function I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
data("mtcars")
mtcars %>% group_by(gear,cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(mpg,na.rm=1),sd=sd(mpg,na.rm=1),n=n())

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   gear [3]
   gear   cyl  mean     sd     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1     3     4  21.5 NA         1
2     3     6  19.8  2.33      2
3     3     8  15.0  2.77     12
4     4     4  26.9  4.81      8
5     4     6  19.8  1.55      4
6     5     4  28.2  3.11      2
7     5     6  19.7 NA         1
8     5     8  15.4  0.566     2
```

Comment: This is the easier dplyr alternative I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
cbind(myData[-ncol(myData)], myData[[ncol(myData)]])

  cyl gears   mean        sd  n
1   4     3 21.500        NA  1
2   6     3 19.750 2.3334524  2
3   8     3 15.050 2.7743959 12
4   4     4 26.925 4.8073604  8
5   6     4 19.750 1.5524175  4
6   4     5 28.200 3.1112698  2
7   6     5 19.700        NA  1
8   8     5 15.400 0.5656854  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, though I'm not fully satisfied in why this is required...

```
>>> myData <- aggregate(mtcars$mpg,
       by = list(cyl = mtcars$cyl, gears = mtcars$gear),
       FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x),
                           n = length(x))) %>%
     do.call(data.frame, .) %>% colnames

"cyl"    "gears"  "x.mean" "x.sd"   "x.n"
```

Now each column is distinct, as opposed to "nested", and I can access each and rename as I like.

I noticed this `do.call` applied in the tutorial I lifted this example from: https://datascienceplus.com/building-barplots-with-error-bars/